# An internal error occurred during: "" in Eclipse / Intershop studio

Tags: eclipse, internals, intershop

I'm working in the latest Intershop studio IDE, which is based on the Eclipse.

I've started to get a strange error lately, which occurs quite often in a lot of actions, I would say at least 15 times/hour. Error makes no sense to me and it is quite annoying. It is visible on the image.

[image]

And here's the stacktrace:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2018-12-07 10:25:17.369
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.BasicEObjectImpl.eURIFragmentSegment(BasicEObjectImpl.java:317)
    at com.intershop.studio.common.tools.EMFUtils.getRelativeURIFragmentPath(EMFUtils.java:670)
    at com.intershop.studio.common.tools.EMFUtils.getID(EMFUtils.java:644)
    at com.intershop.studio.core.ElementOperations.getHREF(ElementOperations.java:160)
    at com.intershop.studio.core.ICoreElement.getHREF(ICoreElement.java:46)
    at com.intershop.studio.core.ElementMarkerOperations.applyElementAttributes(ElementMarkerOperations.java:254)
    at com.intershop.studio.core.validate.Diagnostics2MarkerHandler.adjustMarker(Diagnostics2MarkerHandler.java:206)
    at com.intershop.studio.core.ui.validate.EObjectDiagnosticTempMarker.getAttributes(EObjectDiagnosticTempMarker.java:81)
    at com.intershop.studio.core.ui.validate.EObjectDiagnosticTempMarker.equals(EObjectDiagnosticTempMarker.java:117)
    at java.util.Arrays.deepEquals0(Arrays.java:4299)
    at java.util.Arrays.deepEquals(Arrays.java:4269)
    at java.util.Arrays.deepEquals0(Arrays.java:4281)
    at java.util.Objects.deepEquals(Objects.java:85)
    at com.intershop.studio.common.tools.CommonTools.equals(CommonTools.java:310)
    at com.intershop.studio.core.ui.validate.EObjectLiveMarkerProvider.processValidationResult(EObjectLiveMarkerProvider.java:333)
    at com.intershop.studio.core.ui.validate.EObjectLiveMarkerProvider$ValidationJob.run(EObjectLiveMarkerProvider.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

Is anyone familiar with this, how can I solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Would go with this to intershop support. Seems like their customer plugin isnt working with the new version.